# Access controller plugins in mapper in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am creating an application in zf2.

I have a Plugin (MyModule\Controller\Plugin\MyPlugin) that I can call in my controller without any problem.

I would like to be able to call it from a mapper (like it was possible in zf1 doing getStaticHelper().
I found that it is possible to get it in the view by doing Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance() and then call the plugin but this doesn't work in the mapper.

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add to your module.config.php something like this:

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
'invokables' => array(
    'userauthentication' => 'User\Controller\Plugin\UserAuthentication',
),
```

),

Then you should be able to call it from any controller:

```
$this->userAuthentication()->getAuthService()->hasIdentity();
```

Comment: This is what I did and it works fine if I call it fom my controller (no pb). But if I try to call it from the mapper I have an "Invalid method (userauthentifaction)"